# Passing multiple parameters in DataEventArgs

Tags: c#, event-handling

I am developing a UI, that takes 4 different string parameters. I have to pass these parameters with the help of DataEventArgs which only takes one parameter.(like DataEventArgs) to my code. Kindly give some suggestions and help. This is using C#.

Thanks you

Comment: You cannot create a new EventArgs subclass and forced to use the DataEventArgs class? Or can you subclass DataEventArgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyEventsArgs:EventArgs
{
     public MyEventsArgs()
     {

     }

     public int prop1 { get; set; }
     public int prop2 { get; set; }
     public int prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

e.g.:

```
yourUI1.YourEvent += new EventHandler(hndlr);

public void hndlr(object obj, EventArgs args)
{
    MyEventsArgs myArgs = (MyEventsArgs)args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inherit EventArgs and make a new class that has the members(4 parameters) you need.
you will still pass EventArgs to the UI but it will have your CustomEventArgs inside, and you can cast it back to CustomEventArgs and use it.